# Can we classify commuting pairs of matrices up to conjugacy?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, modules

Recall that two $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same [Jordan canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_canonical_form).

**Question.** Is there a similar classification for commuting pairs of matrices?

To be precise, a *commuting pair* of matrices is an ordered pair $(A,B)$ of $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$ for which $AB=BA$. Two commuting pairs $(A,B)$ and $(A',B\,')$ are *conjugate* if there exists a nonsingular matrix $P$ so that
$$
PAP^{-1} = A'\qquad\text{and}\qquad PBP^{-1} = B\,'.
$$
What are the equivalence classes under this relation?  Can we enumerate them?  Can we check whether two pairs are in the same class?

A few notes:

1. If $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable, they can be simultaneously diagonalized, and the resulting pair of diagonal matrices determines the conjugacy class.
2. According to [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49378/simultaneous-jordanization/49393#49393), a commuting pair of matrices cannot in general be  simultaneously Jordanized.
3. According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Simultaneous_triangularisability), a commuting pair of matrices *can* be simultaneously triangularized, but of course the pair of triangular matrices is not uniquely determined.

By the way, this question is equivalent to asking for a classification of [indecomposable modules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_module) over $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ with finite dimension over $\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gelfand and Ponomarev proved, that a category of all artinian modulus over $K[X,Y]$ contains a full subcategory isomorphic to the category $L_k$ of artinian modulus over free algebra on $k$ elements. This subcategory can be constructed explicitly.

So if such classification exists then one can also classify systems of $n$ non-commuting linear operators on up to conjugation. That seems impossible.

Here is a link to the article: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01076321