# If $A,B$ are commuting diagonalizable complex matrices , then $A,B$ have a common eigen-basis ?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A,B$ are diagonalizable complex matrices of size $n$ such that $AB=BA$ , then is there a common eigen-basis of $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: First prove the following: If $AB = BA$, then each eigenspace of $A$ is preserved by $B$.

Comment: Yes. Have a look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/matrices-commute-common-basis-of-eigenvectors