# Eigenvalue of the algebra generated by commuting matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra generated by a set $\mathcal{M}$ of commuting matrices over complex field. What can I say about the eigenvalues of the members of $\mathcal{A}$ in terms of the eigenvalues of the members of $\mathcal{M}$?

If all members of $\mathcal{M}$ are diagonalizable, I think there is a simple relationship. Each member of $\mathcal{A}$ is a form of $f(M_1, \cdots, M_n)$ where $f$ is a polynomial and $M_1, \cdots$ are member of $\mathcal{M}$. Then for each eigenvalue (counting the multiplicity) of $f(M_1, \cdots, M_n)$ there is an eigenvector shared by all members of $\mathcal{A}$. The eigenvalue must be $f(\lambda_1, \cdots, \lambda_n)$ where $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue of $M_i$ corresponding to the common eigenvector.

What relations are there if other conditions are assumed instead of the diagonalizability? I know that the quation is quite broad. But any relations between the eigenvalues may be helpful for me. Thank you.

Comment: Have you googled with the main keywords ? There are many reference on the web. For example (https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_relation_between_eigenvalues_of_two_commuting_matrices). See as well the answer of Jose Brox in (http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1227031)

Comment: Do you know the McCoy theorem? You might look it up. There are also a bunch of other relations bound with it, like semi commuting matrices and other relations.

Comment: @JeanMarie, Of course I have googled, but didn't get much relevant results. I've read your first link, but the second one is new for me. Thank you.

Comment: @Abraham, I didn't aware of the theorem. Thank you.

Comment: Your line of reasoning applies even if the matrices are not diagonalizable; any family of commuting matrices has a common eigenvector.  Moreover, the entire commuting family can be simultaneously brought into upper-triangular form with a unitary similarity.

Comment: With your definition, does the algebra generated by a set include the identity?

Comment: @Omnomnomno, Thank you for pointing the existence of a common eigenvector. I have no condition on the identity. It can be included or not.

Comment: @TameBlie the only change that results from not including the identity is that if all matrices in $\mathcal M$ are not invertible, then it's possible that every element of $\mathcal A$ has $0$ has an eigenvalue.

Comment: Notably, $\mathcal A$ contains the identity if and only if it contains any invertible matrix.