# The problem of the commutator of Hermitian operators

Tags: operator-theory, physics, quantum-mechanics

Well, I'm a little confused. Suppose we have three Hermitian operators

$\widehat A = \widehat A^{\dagger}$

$\widehat B = \widehat B^{\dagger}$

$\widehat C = \widehat C^{\dagger}$.

We know that $[\widehat A, \widehat B] = i \widehat C $ and $[\widehat A,\widehat C] = 0$.

So, we know that $\widehat A f(a) = a f(a) $ because it's its own representation.

But what about $\widehat B f(a) = ?$

I am sure that I can make some statement from above commutation properties. But I can't write smth expect well-known bacics.

Comment: Is $f(a)$ an eigenvector of $\hat A$ with eigenvalue $a$?

Comment: @KennyWong yes, for sure

Comment: Could you please say where the commutation relations come from? I'm struggling to see any nice properties of $\hat B f(a)$ (but this might be because I'm being dumb).

Comment: In the case that $A$ is not degenerate (only simple eigenvalue), the result is somewhat nice since $A$ and $C$ share eigenvectors, say $Cf(a)  = cf(a)$, as the second answer addresses [here][1].

Simply starts with $[A,B]f(a) = iCf(a)$. note that $A$ commutes with $C$, further assume $A$ is invertible, then:
$$(I - aA^{-1})B f(a) = i A^{-1}Cf(a) = icA^{-1}f(a) = i\frac{c}{a}f(a)$$
Assume $(I - aA^{-1})$ is invertible,
$$Bf(a) = \frac{ic}{a}(I - aA^{-1})^{-1}f(a)$$
Still :(.


  [1]: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227031/do-commuting-matrices-share-the-same-eigenvectors

Comment: I can do it if $C$ is a constant

Comment: @Paichu however the right answer is $i C(a) \frac{d}{da}$, where $C(a) = \widehat C f(a)$. I don't get it.

Comment: Let me finish some grading first, and I'll try working that out this afternoon.

Comment: Similar to before,
$$Bf(a) = \frac{iC}{a}(A - aI)^{-1}f(a)$$

Since $Af(a) = af(a)$, then $A^{-1}f(a) = \frac{1}{a} f(a)$. And, $(A-aI)^{-1}$ will have eigenvalue of something like $\frac{1}{a - a}$, not really, so here is the very informal part, but it will help with the intuition. 
Note the strange eigenvalue of $(A-aI)^{-1}$, this can be interpreted like this
$(A-aI)^{-1}f(a) = f(a) \lim_{\Delta a \rightarrow 0}\frac{...}{\Delta a}$. In a way the right part after $f(a)$ is a derivative, thus you can obtain your answer. This is not at all rigorous, but I hope it provides some insight.

Comment: @Paichu I can tell you that I tried to get it with methods like how it is shown for operators $x$ and $ p_x$. Note that $[x,p_x]=i\hbar$, $[x,\hbar] = 0$ and $\widehat xf(x) = xf(x)$. But it is common knowledge that $\widehat p f(x) = -i \hbar\, \frac{d}{dx} f(x)$. But something wrong with me. I can't get it with analogical methods for common $A,B,C$

Answer (score 2):

First off, let us skip the obnoxious carets, since capital letters suffice to denote operators.

Secondly, and most importantly, you must also assume $[B,C]=0$ as well, so its eigenvalues in any representation must be constants ($\hbar$), since the [magic that leads to Weyl's braiding relation in QM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Application_in_quantum_mechanics) will not work, and the relevant  Campbell-Baker-Haussdorf expression will be hellishly complicated, in general, depending on the functional dependence of *C(A)*.  So I assume it forthwith.

Thirdly, your major snagging point seems to be in the setup of your representation. Dirac (Principles of QM, Ch III.20) spends a long time in his book doing it right, but most people never get to use it much, since it is mostly "monkey-see-monkey-do" in 99.9% of the applications.

In any case, using Dirac's "standard ket", $|\varpi\rangle$, the translationally invariant vacuum, you define your rep as follows,
$$
f(a)=\langle a| F(A)|\varpi \rangle ,
$$
leading to the statement you express informally, 
$$
\langle a| A F(A)|\varpi \rangle  =a~ f(a),
$$
with normalization $\langle a|\varpi\rangle =1$, and $|a\rangle \propto \delta(A-a)|\varpi\rangle $. *F* is the power series of *f*, essentially *f(A)*.  *All* functions of *a* in this picture are eigenvectors of *A* with the *same eigenvalue a*. Improper appreciation of this statement leads to ambiguities and no end of grief.

Then, the standard argument of QM unfolds easily, upon recognition of the fact that, *C* being a constant commuting with everything, *B* acts like a derivative on all functions of *A*, 
$$
[B,F(A)]=-iC ~ F'(A),
$$
readily derivable from  your commutation relation by considering any power of *A*, and hence a power-series definition of *F*. But recall *C* must be a constant, not an elaborate function of *A*.

Now, it is standard to assume the standard ket to be in the kernel of *B*, ($B|\varpi\rangle=0$, "translational invariance of the vacuum"), whence
$$
\langle a| B F(A)|\varpi \rangle  =\langle a|  F(A) B -iCF'|\varpi \rangle =
\langle a|-iCF'(A)|\varpi \rangle  =   -iC\partial_a f(a),
$$
the familiar representation of the momentum operator.