# For a symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ with $AB=BA$, show that the property $X$ holds

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

For any square matrix $C$ with real entries, define $\lambda_1(C)$ as the maximum of the absolute values of the eigen values of $C$. Two square matrix $A_{n \times n}$ and $B_{n \times n}$ with real entries satisfy  property $X$ if

$$\lambda_1(AB)\leq \lambda_1(A)  \lambda_1(B)$$

1) For a symmetric matrices $A$ and $B$ with $AB=BA$, show that the property $X$ holds.

2) If the condition of symmetry dropped, does the property $X$ still hold?

My work: From the given condition $AB$ is also symmetric and all $A, B, AB$ are diagonalisable. But after that  how do I proceed? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: In the case that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable, it suffices to note that they are necessarily [simultaneously diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/236212/81360)

Comment: I suspect that property $X$ can be shown to hold in general using continuity arguments

Comment: @ Omnomnomnom , but how?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603375/norm-of-a-symmetric-matrix-equals-spectral-radius might be of some help?

Answer (score 1):

The following post shows that $\lambda_1 (A)$ is same as the norm of the matrix A. It is well-known that $||AB|| \leq ||A|| ||B||$. Hence 1) holds even if $AB \neq BA$. 2) is false. Try $2X2$ matrices.
[Norm of a symmetric matrix equals spectral radius](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/603375/norm-of-a-symmetric-matrix-equals-spectral-radius)

Comment: Ohh nice.......

Comment: I thought about posting the same thing, but I'm just wondering about $AB$. It doesn't need to be symmetric even if $A$ and $B$ are, so its maximum modulus of eigenvalues need not be its spectral radius.

Comment: But of course, if $AB = BA$, then $AB$ is symmetric!

Answer (score 0):

According to Burnside Theorem for matrix algebras, see the bottom of page 3 of [these notes](http://www.joelshapiro.org/Pubvit/Downloads/BurnsideThm/burnside.pdf), we can restrict to the case of upper triangular matrices $A$ and $B$, as $A$ and $B$ can be simultaneously upper-triangularized. This is a similarity operation, which does not disturb eigenvalues. See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1832221).

Now let $A$ and $B$ be upper-triangular.
We can read-off the eigenvalues of $AB$ from its diagonal, whose entries are $a_{ii}b_{ii}$. Thus the eigenvalues of $AB$ are products of diagonal entries of $A$ and $B$, which are itself their eigenvalues. Hence the claim follows.