# If $S,T$ are linear operators on $V$ over $\mathbb{C}$ and $ST = TS$ show there exist one common eigenvalue of $S$ and $T$

Tags: linear-algebra

I think I have to show that $Sx = \lambda_S x$ and $Ty = \lambda_T y$ with $\lambda_S = \lambda_T$? I tried doing $TSx = T\lambda_S x = STx \implies S(Tx)= \lambda_S Tx$

and $STy = S\lambda_Ty = TSy \implies T(Sy) = \lambda_T Sy$

but this isn't leading anywhere. Can I get a hint or something?

Comment: Try $S=\lambda I$ and $T=\mu I$.

Comment: @A.Γ. why are we allowed to do that? They are arbitrary

Comment: To get a contradiction with your statement.

Comment: Both the above comment and answer below provide counterexamples to your statement.

Answer (score 1):

It's not true, as you can see if $V$ is one-dimensional, in which case all linear operators commute with each other.

Comment: Assume over $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: It should be a 'common eigenvector' and in that case mse has an answer already here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227031/do-commuting-matrices-share-the-same-eigenvectors

Comment: You are right. I completely misread the original question, that's why I had so much trouble with this question.