# To show orthogonal basis exist consisting common eigenvectors

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, bilinear-form

Let $h$ be a positive definite hermitian form on $E$ and $A,B: E\rightarrow E$ be
two hermitian endomorphisms which commute, $AB = BA$. Prove that there exists a
orthogonal basis for $E$ consisting of common eigenvectors for $A$ and $B$.

Serge Lange,"Algebra" Chapter 15,Question 4

Can you please give any hint?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/matrices-commute-if-and-only-if-they-share-a-common-basis-of-eigenvectors

Comment: But there we are not using that $A,B$ are hermitian endomorphism. And we want a orthogonal basis. Do we get orthoganal basis using orthogonality process??

Comment: hermitian implies that they are individually diagonalizable. then commutativity is equivalent to having a common basis of eigenvectors. the orhogonality follows from the fact that the eigenspaces are ortghogonal