# If $A$ and $B$ are commuting Hermitian matrices, then they have the same eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-adjoint-operators

If $AB = BA$ and both $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian matrices, then I can show that if $Av = \lambda v$, then $ABv = BAv = B\lambda v = \lambda Bv$. So $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ as well.

Where I am stuck is how this implies that $v$ must also be an eigenvector of $B$?

Comment: It doesn't${}$.

Comment: The crucial thing to prove is that each eigenspace of $A$ is invariant under $B$.

Comment: You should always consider trivial cases to check a statement. Here $A=I$ is commuting with any matrix. But it's quite clear that any non zero vector could not be automatically an eigenvector of $B$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the exact result stated in your question isn't true. What is true is that $A$ leaves the eigenspaces of $B$ invariant and vice versa. If $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then
$$
A(Bv) = (AB)v = (BA)v = B(Av) = B(\lambda  v) = \lambda (Bv)
$$
Thus, $Bv$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Let $V_\lambda(A)$ denote the subspace of eigenvectors of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. We have shown $B(V_\lambda(A)) \subset V_\lambda(A)$. This is the result that holds in general.

If $V_\lambda(A)$ is one dimensional, we easily obtain a result that looks like the result you were originally after. Take $v \in V_\lambda(A)$. Then $Bv \in V_\lambda(A)$, so, since $V_\lambda(A)$ is one dimensional, $Bv = \xi v$. In words, if $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with nondegenerate eigenvalue  $\lambda$, then $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$.

There's more to say about this, but I think this answer beat me to the punch [Matrices commute if and only if they share a common basis of eigenvectors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/matrices-commute-if-and-only-if-they-share-a-common-basis-of-eigenvectors)

In general, the result you're thinking of is true, you just have to phrase it correctly. It's *not* the case that *every* eigenvector of $A$ is an eigenvector of $B$. The correct statement is that there exists a *basis* of vectors $v_1 , \ldots , v_n$ for the space such that $v_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$ and $B$ for all $i$. The truth of this statement requires that $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable, which is necessarily true if $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to prove is in fact false. Consider the commuting Hermitian matrices
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&1
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad\text{ and }\qquad
B=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\
0&2
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Clearly $(1,1)$ is an eigenvector of $A$ but not of $B$.