# Dimension of the space of matrices which is commutative to a given matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Suppose I have a matrix $A $ in the space $ V $ of $n $ by $n $ matrices. Then it is quite clear that $S=\{B : AB=BA\} $ form a subspace. I want to find out its dimension. I think it depends on the rank of $A $.

I'm trying the simplest case : $A $ has full rank.
If $X$ is commutative with any other elements of $V $, then $X $ belongs to $S$. It is only the multyple of the identity matrix. So $1\leq \text {dim} S $.

But It's hard for me to make any other proper upper bound.

Comment: The simplest case is when $A=0$.  I don't know the answer to this, but I suspect it's related to the pattern of zeros in $A$, though this is clearly insufficient by itself.  Look at https://yutsumura.com/basis-for-subspace-consisting-of-matrices-commute-with-a-given-diagonal-matrix/ for a start.

Comment: @saulspatz That problem suggest that If $A=\text{daig}(a_1,...,a_1, a_2, ....,a_2, ..., a_n, ... ,a_n)$ while $a_i$ appears $d_i$ times, then $\text{dim} S= \sum {a_i ^2}$. So it gives full answer for diagonalizable $A$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rank of $A$ has nothing to do with it. For a cheap counter-example, consider that the zero matrix (rank 0) and the identity matrix (full rank) both commute with every matrix and hence $S$ would have dimension $n^2$ for both.

You may find it useful to know that [two matrices commute if and only if they preserve each other's eigenspaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6258/matrices-commute-if-and-only-if-they-share-a-common-basis-of-eigenvectors). If you think about this a bit harder (or a lot harder and know some Lie algebra theory), you might come to some of the following....

> [Commuting Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commuting_matrices#Characterizations_and_properties)
>  [Burnside's Theorem](http://www.joelshapiro.org/Pubvit/Downloads/BurnsideThm/burnside.pdf)
>  [Lie-Kolchin Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie%E2%80%93Kolchin_theorem#Lie's_theorem)